# How can one see what information is being shared when getting notified that “this allows the app in the websites to share information about you”?

Tags: iphone, ios, login, privacy, google

I installed [Adobe Premiere Rush](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/adobe-premiere-rush-edit-video/id1188753863) on my iPhone 12, which runs iOS 15. When I attempt to login via Google, I get notified that:

> this allows the app in the websites to share information about you

as shows in the screenshot below.

How can one see what  information is being shared when getting notified that “this allows The app in the websites to share information about you”?

[image]

Comment: That's using your Google account (or your Apple ID, or Adobe ID, or Facebook account) to log into something. Do you know what it is you're logging into?

Comment: @benwiggy it is logging into my Adobe account

Comment: (https://helpx.adobe.com/manage-account/using/access-adobe-id-account.html)